# Tabela de dispersão (Hash Tables)

Tags: c, hashmap

Tenho uma *hash table* fechada com endereçamento aberto e sondagem linear para o seguinte dicionário de palavras, de um texto;

A operação de entrada funciona assim:

**1)** O programa pede a primeira linha do texto (com limite de 100 caracteres)
   nesse momento eu vou quebrando o texto, e adicionando as palavras na tabela hash;
   depois pede a 2ª linha...
   continuará pedindo as linhas até encontrar uma linha chamada $STOP

**2)** Após o `$STOP`, o programa pede palavras(strings) p/ ser buscada na hash, o resultado da busca será o número da(s) linha(s) de incidência daquela palavra no texto;

```
//EXEMPLO:
$START
o mundo era bonito demais
o mundo jah foi muito belo 
$STOP
mundo
bonito
//retornará:
mundo: 1 2
bonito: 1
```

Considerando que o número de chaves podem variar de 1 até n (10000 por exemplo) palavras distintas, como devo administrar o tamanho da minha tabela? Devo colocar um vetor tabela[10001]?

Será que não irá gastar muita memória?

Como lidar com esse problema do *hash table* fechada com endereçamento aberto e sondagem linear"?

Comment: Isso ta com uma cara de lição de casa...

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: Não tem problema ser lição de casa se a pergunta ainda for bem feita. o pcccj Fez uma pergunta clara e está perguntando sobre um detalhe do problema dele, sem pedir pra alguém fazer a tarefa toda pra ele.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: Na verdade é sim amigo. Mas a pergunta envolve, talvez, 5% desta lição. Mas mesmo se não fosse, um dia teria essa curiosidade(e talvez muitas pessoas já a tenham), então, ajude sem julgar. Não estou te pedindo um programa e sim um conselho/dica. Abraço

Comment: Foi só um comentário inocente, juro. Desculpe se pareceu crítica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma coisa muito importante para se ter em mente ao usar tabelas hash, especialmente com endereçamento aberto, é o *load factor*: a razão entre o número de chaves distintas na tabela e a capacidade máxima da tabela. Se o *load factor* for muito baixo você estará desperdiçando memória com uma tabela hash demasiadamente esparsa. Por outro lado, se o *load factor* for muito alto, você fica muito propenso à colisões na sua função de hash e formações de *clusters* na sua tabela (segmentos longos de índices ocupados, que significam sondagens lineares também longas...). Por exemplo, imagine o que ocorre com uma tabela de capacidade 10001 com 10000 chaves usadas, como a que você propôs na pergunta: vai ter 10000 índices consecutivos usados e apenas um índice livre sobrando. Ao tentar inserir o 10001<sup>o</sup> elemento, é quase certeiro que haja uma colisão da função de hash e na média você terá que fazer uma sondagem de 5000 índices até chegar no balde vazio!

Por causa disso tudo, o ideal é que o seu *load factor* não seja nem muito grande nem muito pequeno. A [wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) diz que se você estiver usando endereçamento linear, é bom evitar load factors acima de 70% ou 80% (mas não achei a fonte pra esse número específico). É claro, isso tudo depende da função de hash que você estiver usando e do texto que você usar como entrada. Sugiro que você faça testes com capacidades diferentes e veja os resultados.

Fora isso tudo, se você não souber a priori a capacidade da tabela que você vai precisar uma possibilidade é redimensionar a tabela dinamicamente. Toda vez que o load factor passar de um limite preestabelecido, você malloca uma nova tabela com o dobro<sup>1</sup> da capacidade e transfere todas as chaves da tabela antiga pra tabela nova.

---

<sup>1</sup> O que importa aqui é sempre multiplicar a capacidade por uma constante maior que 1 (crescer as capacidades exponencialmente) ao invés de ficar aumentando por um número fixo de elementos (crescer a capacidade linearmente). Isso faz com que o custo assintótico amortizado dos redimensionamentos seja constante. Quanto maior o fator de redimensionamento, menos tempo você vai gastar com redimensionamentos mas em compensação você vai ter tabelas gastando mais memória.

Comment: primeiramente muito obrigado, seu conselho abriu meus caminhos. Entretanto tou com problemas com a função que tem o dever de passar o conteúdo da tabela1 pra tabela2(tabela maior);

Comment: Expressei minha dúvida nesse post: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38489/duvida-hash-table