# Hash Table para incidência de palavras em texto

Tags: c, hash, hashmap

---

#### Este problema foi melhor ilustrado aqui: [Erro em copiar vetor de tipo estruturado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38551/erro-em-copiar-vetor-de-tipo-abstrato)

---

#### Resumo:

Estou desenvolvendo um dicionário de índices, que armazena a incidência de uma palavra do texto (de entrada) utilizando uma *hash table* fechada de endereçamento aberto com sondagem linear (*linear probing*); E estou tendo um erro um tanto estranho.

Ex:

```
 O mundo eh belo   [linha1]
 O mundo eh bacana [linha2]
```

chave = mundo; linhas= 1 e 2; num de incidências = 2;

Tenho o seguinte tipo estruturado:

```
typedef struct dicionario
{
 char chave[21];//recebe uma string

 int* linhas;//recebe um vetor de inteiros

 int tam_linhas;//tamanho do vetor de inteiros

}Dicionario;
```

Primeiro, inicializo Dicionário* tabela, e malloco o mesmo. Segundo, inicializo Dicionário* `tabela2`, mas não malloco;

`tabela2` vai ser minha tabela reserva, que só irei mallocar e utilizar quando meu LOAD_FACTOR<sup>1</sup> for maior que 0.5;

Quando meu `load_factor`<sup>1</sup> for maior, eu aloco espaço pra `tabela2`, que terá aproximadamente dobro do tamanho de tabela, e invoco uma função<sup>2</sup> que tem como objetivo passar todos os elementos de tabela pra `tabela2`;

Entretanto não funciona, pois, nada de `tabela2` é alterado pela função<sup>2</sup>. E se tento alterar pela `main()`, acontece um erro.

O código se encontra aqui: http://ideone.com/rbhYhZ

Só preciso conseguir fazer com que essa função<sup>2</sup> funcione devidamente;

---

<sup>1</sup> razão entre o número de chaves distintas na tabela e a capacidade máxima da tabela

<sup>2</sup>`void reallocaTabela(Dicionario* tabela, Dicionario* tabela2, int tam, int tam_antigo)`

Comment: Seu código está meio comprido demais pra uma pergunta do Stackoverflow. Você achq que você consegue reduzir pra algo pequeno o suficiente pra incluir no próprio post, sem links para sites externos? É melhor evitar um links externos pq ele pode parar de funcionar no futuro e menos pessoas tem tempo de achar um bug em 300 linhas.

Comment: Não olhei a parte da realocação em detalhe mas tem algumas outras coisas que são confusas no seu código: 1) a sua estrutura de dados pro dicionário está muito esquisita. O normal seria armazenar só a chave e o número de ocorrências em cada balde. Não sei o que linhas e tam_linhas estão fazendo aí. 2) Eu acharia melhor usar `char *` ao invés de `char []` no balde da hash table; isso permite palavras maiores e facilita sua vida na hora de inserir e transferir itens da tabela. 3) O idiomático é usar 1 ao invés de 'S' e 0 pra 'N'. Se vc puder usar c99 tb tem `true` e `false`, que é melhor ainda.

Comment: Finalmente, a função de realocação está muito comprida e tem muito codigo copiado da sua "main". Se você tivesse extraído a lógica de inserção em uma subrotina reutilisável vc poderia escrever a realocação em umas 3 ou quatro linhas, simplesmente pegando todo mundo da tabela 1 e reinserindo na tabela 2.  Como escolher os parametros e valores de retorno da função compartilhada de inserção pra tudo dar certo fica como exercício :)

Comment: Uma outra sugestão mais subjetiva é que eu acho que fica mais claro usar `return` ou `break` pra interromper os loops ao invés de encher o código de "bandeiras" como "op_efetuada". Nem todo mundo concorda com isso mas eu acho que que quanto menos variáveis interferindo no fluxo do programa melhor.

Comment: @hugomg Obrigado pelas sugestões!

Comment: @hugomg, pensando no que vc me disse, refiz tudo, isolando o meu problema. Criei uma nova pergunta, veja se consegue compreender agora: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38551/erro-em-copiar-vetor-de-tipo-abstrato

Comment: nai precisava criar uma pergunta nova. vc podia ter editado a antiga.