# Erro em copiar vetor de tipo estruturado

Tags: c, array

Erro em copiar elementos de um vetor de **tipo estruturado** para outro vetor **do mesmo tipo**:

No fim do código abaixo, utilizo uma função para "printar" todos os elementos da `tabela2` (vetor que receberá o conteúdo de tabela), mas os prints saem "vazios".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct dicionario
{
  char chave[21];//string de até 20 caracteres

  int* linhas;//vetor de inteiros

  int tam_linhas;//tamanho do vetor acima;

}Dicionario;

void verificaAlocacao(Dicionario* tabela)
{
    if(tabela == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nmemoria insuficiente");

        exit(1);
    }
}

void inicializa(Dicionario* tabela, int tam)//atribui para todos ->tam_linhas = 0;
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < tam; i++)
        tabela[i].tam_linhas = 0;
}

void reallocaTabela(Dicionario* tabela, Dicionario* tabela2, int tam, int tam_antigo)
{
    int i,
        pos=0,
        k;

    char op_efetuada;//BREAK

    for(i=0; i < tam_antigo; i++)
    {
        op_efetuada == 'N';

        if(tabela[i].tam_linhas != 0)//se tam_linahs != 0
        {

            while(op_efetuada == 'N')
            {
                strcpy(tabela2[pos].chave, tabela[i].chave);//atualiza a chave

                tabela2[pos].tam_linhas = tabela[i].tam_linhas;//atualiza o tamanho das linhas

                tabela2[pos].linhas = (int*) malloc(tabela2[pos].tam_linhas*sizeof(int));//cria o vetor de linhas

                if(tabela2[pos].linhas == NULL)//verifica alocacao
                {
                    printf("\nmemoria insuficiente");

                    exit(1);
                }

                for(k=0; k < tabela2[pos].tam_linhas; k++)//copia elemntos do vetor de linhas
                    tabela2[pos].linhas[k] = tabela[i].linhas[k];

                op_efetuada = 'S';
            }

            pos++;
        }
    }
}

void printTabela(Dicionario* tabela2, int tam)
{
    int l,y;

    for(l=0; l < tam; l++)
    {
        if(tabela2[l].tam_linhas != 0)
        {
            printf("%s",tabela2[l].chave);

            printf(" - tam_linhas: %d - vetor:",tabela2[l].tam_linhas);

            for(y=0; y < tabela2[l].tam_linhas; y++)
                printf("[%d]", tabela2[l].linhas[y]);

            printf("\n");

        }
        else
            printf("[vazio]\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int tam=3;//tamanho da tabela

    Dicionario* tabela = (Dicionario*) malloc(tam*sizeof(Dicionario));

    Dicionario* tabela2;

    verificaAlocacao(tabela);

    inicializa(tabela, tam);

    ///ATRIBUI VALORES PARA TABELA

        //na posicao [0]
        strcpy(tabela[0].chave, "bola");//chave = bola

        tabela[0].linhas = (int*) malloc(3*sizeof(int));//atualiza vetor de linhas
            tabela[0].linhas[0]=0;
            tabela[0].linhas[1]=1;
            tabela[0].linhas[2]=2;

        tabela[0].tam_linhas =3;//atualiza tam de linhas

        //na posicao [2]
        strcpy(tabela[2].chave, "carro");//chave = carro

        tabela[2].linhas = (int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
            tabela[2].linhas[0]=2;
            tabela[2].linhas[1]=9;

        tabela[2].tam_linhas =2;

    ///FIM

    tabela2 = (Dicionario*) malloc((2*tam +1)*sizeof(Dicionario));

    verificaAlocacao(tabela2);

    reallocaTabela(tabela, tabela2, (2*tam +1), tam);

    printTabela(tabela2,(2*tam +1));

    return 0;
}
```

Qual é o problema?

Comment: Procure formatar o código corretamente para facilitar para as pessoas que podem te ajudar. Utilize o ícone **`{}`** na edição. Além disto observe algumas coisas coisas que fazemos aqui diferente de fóruns. Aqui temos apenas **perguntas** e **respostas**, não "conversas". http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-agradecimentos Vai aprendendo quando as pessoas editam seus posts como é o estilo correto.

Comment: @bigown Desculpe, mas a ferramenta de inserção de código não é das melhores! ``[codigo]`` = parece não funcionar para códigos com mais de 50linhas

Comment: Acabou de funcionar comigo. Veja como está agora. É extremamente simples. programar é várias ordens de magnitude mais difícil que usar a formatação.

Comment: Sim, de fato. Vou procurar melhorar nesse sentido. Mas espero que no futuro a experiencia do usuário aumente no que se diz respeito a ferramenta de formatação. Pois não está competindo ao nível dos outros fóruns. Obrigado

Comment: O stackoverflow usa formatação markdown e pra formatar o código ele tem que estar todo indentado 4 espaços. A maneira mais fácil de fazer isso é selecionar tudo e apertar o botaozinho de `{}` na barra de ferramentas.

Comment: @hugomg Desse jeito realmente ficou como eu queria. Obrigado

Comment: E evite ficar postando várias vezes o mesmo problema. Quando tiver que mudar algo, você deve [edit] a pergunta para ajustar e ficar de forma que todos possam entender. Aqui não é um fórum, edições fazem parte da experiência com o usuário para que tenhamos boas perguntas e respostas e pouco ou nada de ruído.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava na incongruência de algumas passagens da função `reallocTabela()`;

por exemplo na passagem: `op_efetuada == 'N';`, o qual ao invés de utilizar o simbolo de incremento(`=`), acabou-se utilizando o simbolo de igualdade(`==`);